# Create linked server from code first migraiton

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, linked-server

I am using entity framework 6 with a code-first approach.  I have a need to create a linked server and I'm not sure where to do this.

I only want it to run once.  I think I should create a migration for this but I get this error:

*The procedure 'sys.sp_addlinkedserver' cannot be executed within a transaction.*

What is the best way to do this?
I am okay with doing it before the migrations start but I can;t find where to put that.

Comment: How are you calling the addlinkedserver stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

EF tries to manage the transactions for you.
And as the error suggests the SP can not be called inside a transaction.
If you must use the EF -> SQL command approach
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738523(v=vs.100).aspx

However,
This type of activity is clearly not DB neutral.
So its easier and in my view better just to call the DB directly.

Call SQL server using SQL code directly.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171921.aspx

Comment: I don't see how the links you provided are relevant to the question?  Could you please give an example of the usage you have in mind?

Comment: Link explains the transaction restriction. The second link shows how you can manipulate Databases in a way that MIGHT be useful or interesting as it can help with ADD database process.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Put it in your migration script with `suppressTransaction` set to `true`.

EF6:

```
Sql(linkedServerScript, suppressTransaction: true);
```

EF7:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql(linkedServerScript, suppressTransaction: true);
```